# RxBinding2 Chain with 2 Network Calls - SearchViewQueryText

Tags: rx-java2, rx-binding

I have an `RxBinding2` in my `View` that looks like the below:

```
@Override
public Observable<SearchViewQueryTextEvent> searchIntent()
{
    return RxSearchView.queryTextChangeEvents(searchView)
            .debounce(500, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter(searchViewQueryTextEvent -> searchViewQueryTextEvent.queryText().length() > 2);
}
```

The method I want to call subsequently looks like this:

```
return discogsService.getSearchResults(searchTerm, mContext.getString(R.string.token))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMapIterable(RootSearchResponse::getSearchResults)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap(searchResult ->
                {
                    if (searchResult.getType().equals("release"))
                    {
                        Log.e("DiscogsInteractor", "In release");
                        return discogsService.getRelease(searchResult.getId(), mContext.getString(R.string.token));
                    }
                    else if (searchResult.getType().equals("artist"))
                    {
                        Log.e("DiscogsInteractor", "In artist");
                        return discogsService.getArtist(searchResult.getId(), mContext.getString(R.string.token));
                    }
                    Log.e("DiscogsInteractor", "EmptyObject");
                    return new EmptyObject();
                });
```

I want to set this up in my `Presenter` so that it will reactively call a method. When I call the below on its own in my Presenter, it works fine:

```
mInteractor.searchDiscogs(searchQuery)
    .subscribe(o -> Log.e(TAG, o.toString()));
```

However, I'm struggling to link up that `RxBinding` to then call the above method with the input in the `SearchView`. Here's what I've tried:

```
CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();

disposable.add(mView.searchIntent()
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<SearchViewQueryTextEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onNext(SearchViewQueryTextEvent searchViewQueryTextEvent)
                {
                    mInteractor.searchDiscogs(searchViewQueryTextEvent.toString()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<Object>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d)
                        {
                            Log.e(TAG, "test"); <--- ObservableObserveOn
                        }

                        ...

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete()
                        {
                            Log.e(TAG, "test");
                        }
                    });
                }

                ...
```

`onNext()` gets called correctly but when passing into `searchDiscogs(...)` it will execute up to the line (but not inside of) `.flatMap(...)` and will then return `ObservableObserveOn` to the `onSubscribe(...)`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mInteractor.searchDiscogs(searchViewQueryTextEvent.toString())`

should have been

`mInteractor.searchDiscogs(searchViewQueryTextEvent.queryText().toString())`